# How can i use filter value in a xmlrpc function?

Tags: xml-rpc

I cannot be able to understand this function

```
cancel_var(lcode, rcode[, reason='', send_voucher=0])
```

which should be served by xmlrpg in this way

```
$server = new xmlrpc_client('https://wired.site.net/xrws/');
$args= array(new xmlrpcval($lcode, 'int'), new xmlrpcval($rcode));
$message = new xmlrpcmsg("cancel_var", $args);
```

How can i send this value in php?

```
rcode[, reason='', send_voucher=0]
```

How can i write variable "$rcode" in xmlrpc?

```
$args= array(new xmlrpcval($lcode, 'int'), new xmlrpcval(**$rcode**));
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: i realized that parameters "reason" and "send_voucher" are positional so that shoul be written in this way:
$args= array(new xmlrpcval($lcode, 'int'), new xmlrpcval(**$rcode**), new xmlrpcval(**reason**), new xmlrpcval(**send_voucher**));

Thanks for your attention.